# PHP MySQL dump command

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make this work...
It seems not to be working as expected. I don't know what's wrong. The .sql.gz output file *is empty*... Could you help me?

```
system("mysqldump --host=".$host." --user=".$username." --password=".$password." ".$db." gzip -9 > ".$rep.$db."-".date("d-m-Y-H\hi").".sql.gz");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Of course it's between `<?php` code `?>` tags and an index.php file.

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: In fact it creates the file but it's empty whereas my db is not empty...

Comment: I've put just this after to see errors but there's no errors...

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: If you're meaning to pipe to gzip, you aren't. Double quotes can parse variables, which makes things much easier to read.

Comment: I didn't understood a word... miken32...

Comment: I tried without the "gzip -9" and it's working... without the gz compression. Do you have any idea how to add this gzip function into my code to make it work please?

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution ! I was missing this character "|".
This code is now working:

```
system("mysqldump --host=".$host." --user=".$username." --password=".$password." ".$db." | gzip -9 > ".$rep.$db."-".date("d-m-Y-H\hi").".sql.gz");
```